# SQLite selecting specific field through a query

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database I made that allows you to register your username, password, SAT and ACT test scores. I am relatively new to SQLite and I want to know how would I go about receiving specific values from a database. Basically, how would I go about getting SAT score and ACT score tests values of a specific username that was typed in EditText. I obtain the string from ET and then how do I write a query that returns me these 2 scores of this user that I have?

Comment: info may be [out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlite+android+example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform SELECT query for receive values from table.

For ex:-

SELECT SAT,ACT FROM Table_name WHERE username = 'edittext_value'